# BackgroundWorker works n times for every n-th run of it

Tags: c#, wpf

What's the problem:

I have a wpf app, with a function "install" assigned to a button. It copies and deletes a few files. In button_click function I'm checking if "install" can be run and if it can I'm running it. This function is in another class so I'm running it by:

```
class1 class = new class1();
class.function();
```

and the function is:

```
public void install()
{
    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    worker.DoWork += (s, args) =>
    {
        for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
        {
            //do some work;
            worker.ReportProgress(i);
        }

        MessageBox.Show("done");
    };

    worker.ProgressChanged += (s, args) =>
    {
        // report progress
    };

    worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, args) =>
    {
        worker.CancelAsync();  //not sure if it's needed, it changes nothing
        //reset some values
    };
 }
```

Yeah, something like that. Sorry if it looks a bit retarded but I'm new here and still learning how to paste elements of code :P (if needed i can upload whole project or pastebin some parts)

Whole thing works well, but while I'm clicking install button for 2nd, 3rd, ..., n-th time the worker is doing it's work n times (see the thread name). And I'm out of ideas why.
Am I missing something like worker.close() or whatever ?

EDIT: http://pastebin.com/YR9ZHCCY <- Here, it looks much better

Comment: In your install method do a worker.IsBusy check to prevent running multiple times, "all done" popup should be in worker completed, also you do not need to cancel the async when the work has completed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you handle the button click, you are subscribing your worker method to the `DoWork` event. In C#, delegates are "multicast", meaning that they can have multiple invocation targets. Every time you subscribe the worker method, you add an invocation target, causing that method to be called an additional time. So for N button presses, you get N copies of the same invocation target method in the `DoWork` event delegate.

Likewise the other events, `ProgressChanged` and `RunWorkerCompleted`.

If you want to keep a persistent `BackgroundWorker` instance, you should configure it just once when you initialize it (e.g. by setting properties and events in the Visual Studio Designer). If you want to configure it anew each time the button is clicked, then you should not keep a persistent `BackgroundWorker` instance.

For example, the cheesy approach, add this to the beginning of your `install()` method:

```
if (worker != null)
{
    worker.Dispose();
}
worker = new BackgroundWorker();
```

The non-cheesy approach involves finding the initialization of the BackgroundWorker object and putting all the initialization there. I don't know how this shows up in the WPF designer UI...in Forms, you get a BackgroundWorker component at the bottom of the owner form's design window; you can click the component and then edit the properties and event handlers via the Properties window.

Comment: Could you explain to me what exactly should I do ? I'm a bit noob in wpf :(

Comment: Please see my edited answer. Unfortunately, it's hard to describe the best way to do this because I don't know how you're declaring the BackgroundWorker in the first place. But if you can configure it once in the designer, that would be best.

Comment: Hey. Appreciate your help, but proprably I'm still doing something wrong. Anyway, I have done a new project with only this one function to make sure that problem is only with backgroundworker. And yeah, it is. Here, I packed visual studio 2013 project into a zip file, so if You could take a look :) https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9ee7OsPV7k8RExUd3N4ZGdaX2c/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi. I didn't look at your download link. The instructions in my answer seem pretty clear to me: just add the code I showed, in the location I specified. It may not be the prettiest way to fix your program, but it will do the job. One day, when you've learned to use the VS GUI design tools, a light bulb will go on and you'll understand what I meant about configuring the `BackgroundWorker` once in the design tools, rather than anew each time you want to run the `BackgroundWorker` at run-time.